# How to expand jstree list items in the website using vbscript?

Tags: vba, vbscript

I need to automate some website with vbscript. In here as shown below have some jstree unordered list with list items.

```
<div id="categoryTree" class="category-treeview jstree jstree-1 jstree-default" role="tree" aria-activedescendant="cat35">
<ul class="jstree-container-ul jstree-children">

<li role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false" id="cat001" class="jstree-node  jstree-closed">
<i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
<a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon jstree-themeicon-custom" style="background-image: url(&quot;abc/9174db8b-e42f-41c8-928d-a60c83f3e094.JPG&quot;); background-position: center center; background-size: auto;"></i>A Web Services (AWS)</a>
</li>

<li role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false" id="cat002" class="jstree-node  jstree-closed"></li>
<li role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false" id="cat003" class="jstree-node  jstree-closed"></li>
</ul></div>
```

Ihave try to expand list item using below vbscript code snippet.

```
Set btnTreeListItem = IE.document.getElementById("cat001")
btnTreeListItem.Click
```

But It's nothing happen. So how to do that accordingly?
Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: Probably you need to get the Element ID of that Button you want to click.

Comment: VBA is not the same a vbScript. Please amend tags to reflect which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is the `a` tag that needs clicking then try using a css class selector to target that tag by className

```
ie.document.querySelector(".jstree-anchor").click
```